# Angular - Object are not deleted from browser memory when refreshing

Tags: angular, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I have an quite complex angular app and it causes the browser to crash very quickly. So I am looking to optimize it. I fix every subscription memory leak but the problem is still here. So I use Chrome debug module to try to find the problem. In Memory tab, I do rec session to find whats is going wrong. First I only activate few things to understand. But first problem, when I refresh the browser, old object are still in memory.

For example, here is my app component: I do a get request to get the structure that I store in appService variable.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.appS.restS.get('structure').subscribe((structure: Structure) => {
  this.appS.structure = new Structure(this.type, this.wrapper, structure);
});
```

}

In memory tab, it keep old Structure object:
[image]

Even if I stop "npm start" process. Same Problem. Whats is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Take this with a pinch of salt since I never used the Memory tab before, but as of my understanding you take a snapshot of the tab memory.

If you reload the page the snapshot won't be deleted, which is normal. You are still looking at the old snapshot.

It's like taking a foto, then you reload, and then you watch at the old foto.

If you want to see what has changed you need to take a new snapshot.
Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes I did new snapshot (the image is the new one and it keep old Strcuture Object)

Comment: if you do the same get request twice, why do you expect to have different data? Maybe you can explain your issue better. Are the Structure count keep increasing? if you reload the page you will see 7 Structure?

Comment: Yes I normally just have one structure. But when I move into my app, more structure come. But when I refresh, i get all the old ones + my new one.

Comment: thats stange, usually after a reload everything should be gone. Maybe you have something in the localstorage or a global variable. It's difficult to tell without knowing what `this.appS.` is